# Solution to keep C++ template class code in source file not working

Tags: c++, templates, header-files

I know the typical approach is to implement a templated class in a header. However, I would really like some of the code in a source file and my templated class can only take 2 different types.

I understand there are ways to put the implementation in a source file.

I am following a suggestion here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48575/How-to-Define-a-Template-Class-in-a-h-File-and-Imp

Template class header:

```
#pragma once

template<template<typename> class S>
struct MyClass
{
    void doSomething();
};

#include "MyClass.cpp"
```

Source file:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include <iostream>

template<template<typename> class S>
void MyClass<S>::doSomething()
{
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

Main:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

template<class P>
struct Something{};

int main()
{
    MyClass<Something> mc;
    mc.doSomething();
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting the compiler error:

`void MyClass<S>::doSomething(void)': function template has already been defined`

Can anyone advise how best to achieve this?

Comment: If you put the template implementation in a source file, you will need to "generate" all the template expansions used by the program *in that source file*.  Very manual process, and a maintenance nightmare for mid-sized and larger projects.  (A supplemental implementation header file probably should not be `.cpp`; I'd use `.tpp` or `.ipp` or `.inc`.)

Comment: You should not give the implementation a `.cpp` extension perhaps your IDE is already building the `.cpp` file as part of your project.

Comment: @drescherjm I knocked this example up in VS2019?

Comment: I expect this to definitely be a problem with Visual Studio unless you exclude from building in the "Solution Explorer" or you don't add the .cpp file as part of your project.

Comment: You do realize that by including th `.cpp` file from the header file, the end result is that there's no difference, whatsoever, from having the whole thing in the header file, right? So, why complicate things?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I was just following the guide. I don't know a huge amount about compiling and linking internals (please feel free to share any good resources to read).

Comment: Setting aside that, there's absolutely nothing wrong with the shown code. Cutting/pasting three files, then compiling `main.cpp`, the code compiled just fine. I'm going to guess that you're also compiling and linking `myclass.cpp` as well. You ended up compiling and linking myclass.cpp twice. Once included from `main.cpp`, once by itself. That's a fail.

Comment: @drescherjm I think you're right, VS is causing the issue. What do you mean by excluding from building in the Solution Explorer? How do I not-add the cpp as part of my project?

Comment: Open "Solution Explorer" click on the file `MyClass.cpp` and press delete. Or right click on `MyClass.cpp` and select "Exclude from project"

Comment: @drescherjm Ah nice, very simple. It worked.  Thank you

Comment: @mezamorphic - While it works, it is still a hack. If you have a .cpp file, the compiler - very reasonably - wants to compile and link it to the program. The usual workaround is to give it an extension other than .cpp, like .inc (for include-file), Still, following the rule of "no templates in a .h file" by just giving it another extension is a bit much  "to the letter" for my taste.